# How to get last crawl time of document in Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, web-crawler

How to get last crawl time of document in Sharepoint 2007?

I want to know in which table I will get this information ?

Comment: You would not query a SharePoint database table as this is unsupported. A method using the SharePoint API is required.

Comment: Why we can not query. I am fetching data from sharepoint many time to with the sql query. We can get meta data directly from Database.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of below query you can get last crawl time of document.

```
SELECT LastTouchStart
FROM MSSCrawlURL
WHERE (DisplayURL = '<displayURL>')
```